# How to "import * from module" for nodejs or webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, commonjs

Is there a way to accomplish "import * from module" in nodejs or webpack (using either node's commonjs-style requires, or the newer es6 imports), without abusing the build process?

I have a `mymodule`, and would like it to export symbols for direct injection into the namespace of any `myimportingmodule` which imports mymodule. e.g.

```
exports.commonSymbol = ...
```

then

```
import * ??? / require(???)
console.log(commonSymbol)
```

I am willing to use an extra line of code to do it after the import, and am hoping that line of code does not involve `eval`. I prefer not to use the `with` statement. However if I did have to use eval, I'm curious if that would mess up the current state of tree-shaking/dead-code-elimination.

A language transpiler plugin is perhaps as dubious/viable as abusing the build-process, but those could both be valid answers; an answer that doesn't require tool-level metaprogramming might be preferable though (however I am considering ugly solutions on the level of "if (__bundled_with_tools) {...} else {...}").

---

*minor notes in advance:*

("import * as ns from module" is available in es6, but doesn't work since symbols could only be accessed by `ns.*`)

(One could abuse `global` or `window`, but I would like these symbols to only be available in the importing module. Perhaps that would be the 'best' solution though?)

(I am aware that some people dislike "import *" for the namespace abuse it causes. Looking for an answer besides don't-do-it, but comments to that effect are certainly welcome.)

---

For example, here's a horrible hack that I'm not even sure compiles:

```
_exports = {commonSymbol:'example', ...};
export default makeExportAll(_exports);
export _exports;
```

then

```
import('common').then(eval);  // spec draft level 3... can I even use this in webpack?

// evaluates to eval("etc. etc. making use of _exports, then 
//   this eval then evals dynamically-created 
//   commonSymbol=_exports.commonSymbol, etc.")
```

Anything saner than this...

Comment: The reason this isn't built into the language is the same reason the `with` statement is deprecated. If you can't statically tell where a variable is coming from, it's not only bad for readability, it is bad for optimization and performance.

Comment: I guess one could compile-time concat all files in a directory into one giant file. That basically has the same semantics as what I'm aiming for... I feel dirty for 1) typing this, and 2) typing/thinking my question... but oddly less dirty than other solutions. It may even avoid static-analysis problems on a theoretical level.

Comment: You know the `ns.*` approach, so I guess it really depends how much of a custom build process you really want to avoid it. I don't feel that using a namespace object has ever been that much of a hinderance in my own code though. I'll leave it at that.